# AC analysis on transient model of Buck converter

Tags: ac, buck, switching-regulator, transient

I'm unable to understand why can't we run AC analysis on a transient model of Buck converter.

Comment: Try TI.com's web bench, and Bode plots https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/AND8143-D.PDF

Comment: Okay I'm using Tina software

Comment: V11?  Perhaps direct contact is best.  Not familiar, but looks great. http://www.designsoftware.com/home/English/techsup

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AC analsyis (in the sense the term is used in SPICE) assumes all components in the circuit are linear.

A buck converter only works if some components (the switches) operate nonlinearly.

Therefore, an AC analysis will not capture the useful behavior of a buck converter.

That said, if you consider only frequencies well below the switching frequency, you may be able to use an AC equivalent circuit, with the the switches and inductor modeled as a controlled source, to analyze the control loop and verify such things as the loop stability and phase margin.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, because the SMPS converter is a nonlinear device. You *can* model a SMPS coverter as a Laplace transfer function, presuming someone clever has done the hard lifting for you. For example Robert Sheehan's papers on current mode control theory.

Oddly enough, which some people refuse to believe, current mode control is quite a bit harder to model than voltage mode control. CMC is **easier to use** but the functions provided in application notes usually work only for "normal" use cases. i.e. when you design a low-to-high voltage boost, you can run into trouble as the behavior of the circuit shifts more towards the current controlled loop that many/most formulas "simplify" away.

It's not simple and clever people keep on coming up with improved models occasionally. If you have access to a network analyzer, you can "model" the circuit by measuring it. I haven't looked for many years but that box used to be pretty steeply priced considering what it is and so most designers have to work with SMPS circuits they simply have no means to measure in a meaningful way.